# Android studio test that starts a process run solely on pc

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm currently running tests on android studio using espresso. Some of these test require a device coming close and leaving again (to be moved on command). I have a program to control this device via ssh.

The device is ideally controlled automatically during the test. However, the android phone can't open the ssh connection and it also shouldn't, since this is not part of the app. Ideally the android phone opens a thread that is run by the JVM of my PC on which I know the ssh program works.

Is such a thing possible?

As a backup option, I could have the device write to some file and have a thread on the PC read this file. However, if possible, I would like to avoid this.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

**EDIT:**

I figured out a way to do it using logcat.
Just write the command in a string to logcat. Then the PC can see the command in logcat.

Comment: What do you mean by "coming close and leaving"?

Comment: I test nfc, which requires the chip to come close and leave. For this I use a driving robot that I control over ssh.